# Unable to mount fs, disk slice corrupted

Tags: filesystems, solaris

please can someone help me with this issue. Now when i started sun server - it run on sunfire t100 and os od solaris 5.10, is display this:

checking ufs filesystems
/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s7: BAD SUPERBLOCK AT BLOCK 16: NUMBER OF DIRECTORIES OUT OF RANGE
/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s7: USE AN ALTERNATE SUPERBLOCK TO SUPPLY NEEDED INFORMATION;
/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s7: e.g. fsck [-F ufs] -o b=# [special ...] 
/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s7: where # is the alternate super block. SEE fsck_ufs(1M).

/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s7: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.

THE FOLLOWING FILE SYSTEM(S) HAD AN UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s7 (/export/home)
fsckall failed with exit code 1.

WARNING - Unable to repair one or more filesystems.
Run fsck manually (fsck filesystem...).

svc:/system/filesystem/local:default: WARNING: /sbin/mountall -l failed: exit status 32
Reading ZFS config: done.
Mar 18 13:59:54 svc.startd[7]: svc:/system/filesystem/local:default: Method "/lib/svc/method/fs-local" failed with exit status 95.
Mar 18 13:59:54 svc.startd[7]: system/filesystem/local:default failed fatally: transitioned to maintenance (see 'svcs -xv' for details)

I am connected to server via console. First of all i wanted to increase /var fs because it has only 120mb and shrink /export/home fs. I did it via format utlity but after reboot i was unable to login and disk slice where is /export/home mounted is damaged. But on this fs are no data. Please can somebody help me , i am really desperate, i tried everything that i founf on internet and nothing worked. Please!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and repair using an alternate superblock?

dumpe2fs /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s7 | grep superblock

to get a list of backup superblocks then use one of the backup superblocks with

fsck -b (backup superblock) /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s7